# Programmatically select a row ag-grid + angular 2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Trying to select first row by default in ag-grid. As per ag-grid documents, I should be able to do this using NodeSelection Api(https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0). But I am not able to get to node object at all. 
HTML file

```
<div class="pulldown panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">{{rulesSummaryTitle}}</div>
          <ag-grid-angular #agGrid   class="ag-fresh ag-bootstrap"
                           [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                           [rowData]="rowData"
                           [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                           [enableSorting]="true"
                           rowSelection="single"
                           [pagination]="true"
                           [suppressCellSelection]="true"
                           (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                           (rowSelected)="onRowSelect($event)">
          </ag-grid-angular>
      </div>
```

I am calling node selection api in "onGridReady" method but errors out with error message "cant call setSelected on undefined".

```
public onGridReady(event: any): void {
    event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    this.gridOptions.api.node.setSelected(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found solution, problem was with "onGridReady" function being called well before row data being populated from Observables. So there were actually no rows that select statement could select.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 115px;" class="ag-fresh"
                 [rowData]="rowData"
                 (gridReady)="onReady($event)"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 115px;" class="ag-fresh"
                 [rowData]="rowData2"
                 (gridReady)="onReady($event)"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 115px;" class="ag-fresh"
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [rowData]="rowData3"
                 (gridReady)="onReady($event)"
                 (rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged()"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    columnDefs;
    rowData;
    rowData2;
    rowData3;

    constructor() {
      this.gridOptions = {
      rowData: this.rowData3
    };
      console.log("in here");
      console.log("in here");
      console.log("in here");
        this.columnDefs = [
            {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
            {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
            {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
        ];

        this.rowData = [
            {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
            {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
            {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
        ]

        let val = [
      {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
      {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
      {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
    ];


    let res : Observable<any> = Observable.create(observer => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        observer.next(val);
      },1);
    });
    res.subscribe(
      resposne => {
        this.rowData2 = resposne;
      });

      let res1 : Observable<any> = Observable.create(observer => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        observer.next(val);
      },2000);
    });
    res1.subscribe(
      resposne => {
        this.rowData3 = resposne;
      });


    }
       /**
   * Select the first row as default...
   */
  public onRowDataChanged(): void {
    this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node => node.rowIndex ? 0 : node.setSelected(true));
  }


    private onReady(params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
       params.api.forEachNode(node => node.rowIndex ? 0 : node.setSelected(true));
    }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PSKnSjAo6omDAo5bjm1J.

Added plunker with three ag-grid. First grid has predefined rowdata values,  second grid has rowdata is being populated from Observables but with very less latency, third grid has row data values being populated from observables with higher latency. In case of first and second "onGridReady" function gets called and first row get selected, but in case of third grid we have to provide select row statement on to "rowDataChanged" event for row to be selected.

Comment: thanks, your answer helped. I had to do something similar:
    setTimeout(() => {
        /* select nodes using api */ 
    }, 1);

Answer (score 20):

There isn't a `node` attribute on the `gridOptions.api` object. You will want to do something more like this:

```js
public onGridReady(event: any): void {
  event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node=> node.rowIndex ? 0 : node.setSelected(true))
}
```

This will check over each node in the data and see if the rowIndex is 0, when it is, it uses the node object to set the selected attribute

Comment: There is no behavior change with addition of "gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node=> node.rowIndex ? 0 : node.setSelected(true))" , I don't see any errors nor the first row is selected.

Comment: To verify, there exists any node, I made following changes to code this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode( (node) => {
      let nodeTemp = node;
      console.log("node selected : " + nodeTemp);
    }); but saw that console statement never got executed. Having said that , I do see two rows with data being displayed. I don't understand why there is no nodes.

Comment: Perfect Answer. this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

On onGridReady, you can use this code for selecting first row by default.

```
let  rowIndex = 0;
this.GridOptions.api.paginationGoToFirstPage(); // If pagination is implemented
this.GridOptions.api.selectIndex(rowIndex, false, false);
this.GridOptions.api.setFocusedCell(0, "FirstName");
```

Comment: selectIndex is deprecated => console warning: do not use api for selection, call node.setSelected(value) instead

Answer (score 2):

We need to call the `setSelected(true)` method to select the row node. The main problem is to get the row node.

We can get the row nodes by calling the `getRenderedNodes()` method. According to [the doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/grid-api/#reference-rendering),

> Retrieve rendered nodes. Due to virtualisation this will contain only the current visible rows and those in the buffer.

So, we will get the first row node at index `0` of the array returned by the `getRenderedNodes()` method. The implementation will be the following-

```
public onGridReady(event: any): void {
  let nodes = event.api.getRenderedNodes();
  if (nodes.length) {
    nodes[0].setSelected(true); //selects the first row in the rendered view
  }
}
```

Here's the working plunker demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/J40sUeDSwyDEi76X

Answer (score 0):

try using gridOptions.api.setFocusedCell(0, [column name]) where column name can be ne visible column

Answer (score 0):

aggrid on ready function is not proper for this transact. agon ready just drawing table if you want manipulate data you have to approach before ag ready. but there is no option for this.if you add this code on your methods.

```
getProducts: async function() {
      let data = await repository.getAll("Product").then(r => r.list);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          if (this.value[i].productId == data[j].productId) {
            let x = data.splice(j, 1)[0];
            data.unshift(x);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      this.productDataForAggrid = data;
      this.gridApi.setRowData(this.productDataForAggrid);
      window.watcher = setInterval(this.setSelectedItems, 50, this.gridApi);
    }
```

this function is normal get method except last part. İf you selected some rows on ag and if you close ag all selection will deleted on the table but you stıll have which data selected on your data property when you openin ag again. You will fallow this way.this part of code for real ready function i mean before preparation of data.

```
setSelectedItems(api) {
      if (this.productDataForAggrid.length == api.getDisplayedRowCount()) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) {
          let node = api.getRowNode(this.value[i].productId.toString());
          if (node) {
            node.setSelected(true);
          }
        }
        this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
        clearInterval(window.watcher);
        window.watcher = 0;
        //console.log("ready!");
      }
    }
```

firstly we will add all selected data on value prop for adding to billing list. But if customer wants to reopen product select aggrid again customer cant see the selected products. This getproducts func work for everytime on ag open. and getting all products. compare this data with our value property. and sending to setSelectedItems funciton for check selected.

```
 saveSelectedProducts() {
      this.value.splice(0, this.value.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows().length; i++) {
        if (this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[i].sellPrice === undefined)
          this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[
            i
          ].sellPrice = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[i].odooId;

        if (this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[i].piece === undefined)
          this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[i].piece = 1;

        this.value.push(this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[i]);
      }
      //this.$emit("selectedProductsList", this.value);
      this.openProductPopup = false;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

setSelected(false) can be called on (selectionChanged) event .

One of the grid events available on ag grid public methods