# AgGrid - How can I bind my row selection with a property

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have ag-Grid with huge number of rows. I have another property which if set to true then the rows should be selected. 
I see that we can iterate over the rows and then set the selection to true/false. My collection is large, so I don't want to iterate over each row to set this.
Is it possible to bind this selection to my property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a property to bind the selection as properties like `columnDefs`, `rows`, etc,...

```
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  ....
  [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>`
```

Then the answer is ***NO***.

You'll have to iterate the records to select them.

Another reference: [Programmatically select a row ag-grid + angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45700025/1417185)