# How can I deselect particular values from the Filter List?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Set Filter feature of the `ag-grid` library.

When I load the table with the filter, by default all the values are selected as it is explained in the documentation:

[image: All filter values are selected]

I can deselect all by setting `defaultToNothingSelected` to true.

What I want is not to show the rows that has "Argentina" for example on one of its column fields

**My question is, how can I deselect particular value only from the Filter List of all columns?**

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700025/programmatically-select-a-row-ag-grid-angular-2) that loops through all the nodes `this.grodOptions.api.forEachNode` but I failed to retrieve the filter list values from it.